# Studio Display dimmer than iMacs?

Tags: display, imac

I have several iMacs from 2015 to 2020, and I recently bought a Studio Display for use with my Mac Studio.

But, I find the Studio Display to be dimmer than all my iMacs when the brightness level is the same.

You might say I could just turn up the brightness on the Studio Display, but it's not the same to my eyes. The difference doesn't seem to be fixed by adjusting the brightness setting.

Do you know what's causing this difference? And is there another way to adjust settings on the Studio Display? I heard something about a Monitor Profile?

Comment: I have a Studio Display, and I find that more than 75% Brightness is verging on painful for my eyes! It is a much better display than my old Apple Thunderbolt. Can you explain how the difference isn't fixed by turning it up?

Comment: @benwiggy If I turn brightness up in Studio Display, it has to be about 85-100% for me to feel bright enough to match iMac 50% brightness where I feel comfortable. However, with 85%-100% for Studio Display, if I use it for a longer time, my eyes feel drained.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The only reasons I can think for this are: the settings (on both); some weird bug with the onboard software as a result of strange lighting conditions; a hardware defect. Have you tried turning off the automatic brightness setting?

Comment: automatic brightness setting is already off. I have been using over 5 iMac over 10 years, so I am familiar with iMac brightness. I recently bought a Studio Display, and I found this problem since day 1. After 3 months, I still can't make myself comfortable with Studio Display, so I couldn't help to post a question here to see if anyone feels the same. (iMac & Studio Display inconsistency towards brightness feeling if a user switches back and forth during a day)

Comment: If you can't find anyone else posting about it, then it must be a problem particular to your Display, or some other factor in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard something about a Monitor Profile?

In **System Settings > Display**, there is a preference for the color profile assigned to the display. This is part of the OS color management system, so that colours can be managed across different devices with different physical characteristics.

[image]

If you have chosen one of the other profiles, then the screen brightness might seem lower.

*There used to be an option to manually calibrate the display, but this seems to have gone in Ventura. In fairness, it was usually very difficult to make a better one.*

Also, note the other settings that relate to brightness, which you might want to turn off.

The Studio Display is rated at 600 nits. The 2015 to 2020 5K iMacs are rated at 480 to 500 nits, so you should be seeing a much brighter display on the Studio.

If it's just that the brightness 'seems wrong', it could be that the other displays have a different white point, which is a value in the profile that describes the 'warmth' of white, making it either a bit blue or a bit yellow, and having a relative effect across all colours.

Comment: tbh, with the new displays, it's hard to get a hardware colorimeter to give a better profile, let alone by eye.